# Extract face informations with Ruby

Tags: ruby, face-detection

I'm looking for a ruby library which could extract some informations like eyes space etc ...

I don't want use a remote API, so I found an opencv extension [here](https://github.com/ryanfb/ruby-opencv), but the only thing possible seems to be detect a face.

Will I have to code my own library ?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399748/how-can-i-detect-faces-using-ruby?rq=1.

Comment: I suppose that I'm gonna have to wait for some years ...